# Failing to update a resource name/arn due to missing permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

i'm to implement a custom resource and i'm failing when I try to update its name.

The reason that's i'm failing is that the custom resource lambda is missing the permissions to delete the old resource. since i'm giving it the exact permission by arn, and when I try to change the name of the resource which affects the arn, then it only has permissions for the new resource.

is there any way to solve this wiht giving it permissions for arn:...:/* ?

Here is some code to make this clearer, this implements an SSM SecureString placeholder (since we don't want to deploy secrets that will get away in the stack outputs so just a placeholder)

See code below, note that the policy statement passed to `add_to_policy`, is for `arn:aws:ssm:{region}:{account_id}:parameter/*` - this is the only way it works.
if I try to do minimal privileges, and set it to the specific param name arn, then if I try to update the name, it will fail due to missing permissions to delete the old resource on update.

If I manually added the delete permissions for the old resource (hard coded) it worked.

```
param_name = some-value # This is the ssm param name that is part of the arn
policy = AwsCustomResourcePolicy.from_sdk_calls(resources=[self.arn_join(f'arn:aws:ssm:{region}:{account_id}:parameter', param_name)])
resource = AwsCustomResource(scope=self, id=f'{id_}AwsCustomResource', policy=policy, log_retention=log_retention,
                                            on_create=on_create, on_update=on_update, on_delete=on_delete,
                                            resource_type='Custom::AWSSecureString', 
                                            timeout=timeout)

resource.grant_principal.add_to_policy(iam.PolicyStatement(actions=['ssm:DeleteParameter'], resources=[f'arn:aws:ssm:{region}:{account_id}:parameter/*']))
```

Is it possible to do somehow without giving it '*' permissions for all params?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure what do you want to do. If you provide specific arn, then how can you rename your parameter? The arn will not match the new one, as it will only be valid for the old one.

Comment: @Marcin you are correct of course. but this means that you cannot use custom resource for updating resource name/arn (without giving it full permissions). i'm trying to understand if there's a way to use custom resources for this purpose. (just dreaming here - for example if the custom resource would have two identical policies for the resource, but one would depend on the resource, then it would update after the resource change and then maybe will still give you the old permissions for the update phase before being updated itself, maybe its nonsense :) )